# How would I add a closing quotation to this blockquote?

Tags: html, css

I'm so close, but need some help. Is there any way of adding a close quotation after the sentence, but before the `<cite>`?

Also, how would I center the entire `blockquote` on the page?

http://jsfiddle.net/3PTtv/

```html
<blockquote>
   We came back to IBM because our previous provider was not as awesome.
   <cite>Jon Jones, Vice President at Google</cite>
</blockquote>
```

```css
blockquote {
font-family: Georgia, serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-style: italic;
width: 500px;
margin: 0.25em 0;
padding: 0.25em 40px;
line-height: 1.45;
position: relative;
color: #616161;
}

blockquote:before {
display: block;
content: "\201C";
font-size: 80px;
position: absolute;
left: -20px;
top: -20px;
color: #7a7a7a;
}

blockquote cite {
color: #999999;
font-size: 14px;
display: block;
margin-top: 5px;
}

blockquote cite:before {
content: "\2014 \2009";
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear where you want the closing quotation mark.

Comment: I'd like to closing quotation mark to be on the right side after the sentence, but before the cite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    blockquote {
        color: #616161;
        font-family: Georgia,serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-style: italic;
        line-height: 1.45;
        margin: 0.25em 0;
        padding: 0.25em 40px;
        position: relative;
        quotes: "\201C" "\201D";
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
        color: #7A7A7A;
        display: block;
        font-size: 80px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    blockquote:before {
        content: open-quote;
        left: 0;
        top: -20px;
    }
    blockquote:after {
        content: close-quote;
        bottom: -40px;
        right: 0;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nchqL/21/

Answer (score 7):

just added this classes for closing quotes.

```
blockquote:after {
    display: block;
    content: "\201D";
    font-size: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 40px;
    color: #7a7a7a;
    }
blockquote cite:after {
    content: "\2019 \2009";
    }
```

Here is the Demo. http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/3PTtv/3/

Comment: +1 Beat me to it, I didn't know what the ASCII was for the other quote haha

Comment: Thanks. How do I center the entire quote on the page?

Comment: @user3075987 Wrap the `<blockquote>` in a `<div>` and use the `margin: 0 auto;` CSS trick to center the `<div>` http://jsfiddle.net/A5Nmh/

Comment: Hi, Now the blockquote is centered. Here is the updated Demo. http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/3PTtv/16/

Comment: okay, I've updated your fiddle code. here is the updated one. http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/3PTtv/27/

Comment: Is that work for you now? if yes then vote it and accept the answer.